# Tree Isomorphism Proof

Tags: graph-theory, trees, graph-isomorphism

Okay, I am trying to prove or disprove that "if any two trees have the same number of nodes and every node in tree 1 maps to a distinct node on tree 2 such that they have the same degree, they are isomorphic". I am lost as to how to go about it. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Start with the definition of isomorphism. You know that the number of nodes is the same and that the degrees are the same so that should be enough to construct the map.

Comment: @JohnDouma I recognize that about the question. The issue is that there is no definite characteristic of isomorphism. No equation or relation to go off on. It is basically messing around with it and hoping to find the pattern (at least that is what it has been for me up till now). I am familiar with proofs of trees but there is nothing given to use in a proof here

Comment: @RiverUzoma A tree isomorphism is a bijection that preserves roots and edges. There is no formula. You have to either show that you can always construct such an isomorphism or display two trees with the given properties that are not isomorphic. Take a look at [this](https://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~smal/files/smal_jass08_slides.pdf).

Comment: A counterexample to your question can be two  trees:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
    &   & 6 &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   & | &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
  1 & - & 2 & - & 3 & - & 4 & - & 5 \\
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
    &   &   &   & 6 &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   & | &   &   &   &   \\
  1 & - & 2 & - & 3 & - & 4 & - & 5 \\
\end{array}
$$
Check this.

Comment: @kabenyuk Oh, so it is a disproof. That makes more sense. I was able to prove that two isomorphic graphs will have that list but proving the list ensures isomorphism had me stumped.